# Session not brougt at codeigniter curl request

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

I'm create a remote access using codeigniter curl library from here https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-curl , then using this code below to login, then I get good respons that I've logged in.

```
    $this->load->library('curl');        
    $opt = array(
        'COOKIEJAR' => 'curl_sess/cookie.txt',
        'COOKIEFILE' => 'curl_sess/cookie.txt',
    );

    $array = array(
        'email' => 'user@example.com',
        'password' => 'somepassword'
    );
    echo $this->curl->simple_post('http://remoteweb.com/cek_login', $array, $opt);
```

Then I want to create another request that need logged in status, like :

```
    $array = array();
    echo $this->curl->simple_get('http://remoteweb.com/get_datadeposit', $array);
```

but I get nothing, because my login session at first request not brought in second request.How to achieve this or I missing something ... ?

Comment: Your second simple_get isn't passing `$opt` which I assume contains the cookie information? Is this intentional?

Comment: I've trying both (passing and not passing $opt),but not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$this->load->library('curl');
$opt = array(
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => 'curl_sess/cookie.txt',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
);
$array = array(
    'email' => 'user@example.com',
    'password' => 'somepassword'
);
echo $this->curl->simple_post('http://remoteweb.com/cek_login', $array, $opt);
```